# fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory. though I have included correct folder

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to build a so file in my ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have created a Makefile to do the task. The content of the Makefile is given below

```
#
# 'make depend' uses makedepend to automatically generate dependencies 
#               (dependencies are added to end of Makefile)
# 'make'        build so file 'libwebrtc-aec.so'
# 'make clean'  removes all .o and so files
#

JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_291"

# define the C++ compiler to use
CC = g++

# define any compile-time flags
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
#
INCLUDES = -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux

# define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify
#   their path using -Lpath, something like:
#LFLAGS = -L/home/newhall/lib  -L../lib

# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:
#LIBS = -lmylib -lm
LIBS = -lm

# define the C source files
# $(wildcard *.cpp /xxx/xxx/*.cpp): get all .cpp files from the current directory and dir "/xxx/xxx/"
SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)

# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'
# Below we are replacing the suffix .c of all words in the macro SRCS
# with the .o suffix
#
# $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS)): substitute all ".cpp" file name strings to ".o" file name strings
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))

# define the executable file 
MAIN = libwebrtc-aec

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic; it can be used to 
# build any executable just by changing the definitions above and by
# deleting dependencies appended to the file from 'make depend'
#

.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo  Simple compiler named libwebrtc-ace has been compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -shared -o $(MAIN).so  $(OBJS) $(LIBS) 
#        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .c's
# it uses automatic variables $<: the name of the prerequisite of
# the rule(a .c file) and $@: the name of the target of the rule (a .o file) 
# (see the gnu make manual section about automatic variables)
#.c++.o:
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN).so

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

I can assure that my `JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to correct folder and I have manually checked and found `jni.h` file is present in java home include directory. Still I am getting error like below

```
fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <jni.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I am not sure what did I do wrong. Need help from someone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `.cpp.o` implicit rule, which is (roughly) defined as follows:

```
.cpp.o:
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c $<
```

Your Makefile never sets `CXXFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`, so your `INCLUDES` variable is not used when compiling .cpp files. To fix it, do:

```
CXXFLAGS = $(INCLUDES)
```